# python-telegram-bot error when in Channel

Tags: python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I just finished creating my first bot and it works perfectly in groups and when I message it, however, when I add it to a Channel and give it all permissions it does not work. The echo message function gives an error of `caused error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`.

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
from telegram import MessageEntity, InlineQueryResultArticle, InputTextMessageContent

def echo(update, context): # this is from the documentation
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=update.message.text)

def error(update, context):
    print(f'Error {update} caused error {context.error}')

def main():
    updater = Updater(API)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    
    #Echo message
    echo_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text & (~Filters.command), echo)
    dp.add_handler(echo_handler)

    #Handle errors
    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

main()
```

Comment: seems like `update.message` is being returned as a `NoneType ` , do you give your bot read permission too?

Comment: Within the channel, under Admin rights, it says the bot "has access to messages". Also "Post messages", "Edit messages of others" and "Delete messages of others" are enabled. So I'm assuming it has read permission or is this enabled elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For channel posts it's `update.channel_post` not `update.message.text`. Alternatively, update.effective_message can be used if you don't want to differentiate between channel posts, messages and edited messages/channel posts.

```
def echo(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(
    chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=update.effective_message)
```